# Trigger Event When Reaching A Specific Div

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

So I want to print a number next to the information associated with that number. The problem is that sometimes there are 4 items and sometimes 5 items, meaning I need a counter of some sort. I am trying to trigger an event to print the new number when I reach a specific div. Here is the code:

```
<div class="result">
  <span class="number"><a href="####">####
  <span class="d" id="number">
  </span>
  </span></a> 
<div class="rm">
  <span class="detail"><span class="cloud" title="system"></span> information</span>
  <span class="detail"><span class="marker" title="location"></span> information</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="detail"><span class="cog" title="public"></span> information</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="detail"><span class="lock" title="name"></span> information</span>
  <br/>
</div>
  <span class="default">word</span>
</div>
<div class="result">
  <span class="number"><a href="####">####
  <span class="d" id="number">
  </span>
  </span></a> 
<div class="rm">
  <span class="detail"><span class="cloud" title="system"></span> information</span>
  <span class="detail"><span class="marker" title="location"></span> information</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="detail"><span class="cog" title="public"></span> information</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="detail"><span class="lock" title="name"></span> information</span>
  <br/>
</div>
  <span class="default">word</span>
</div>
```

Essentially, I want to associate the number from span class number with all the information from each detail span. I am putting this into an excel sheet; the number is in column A and information in column B. Is there a way with BeautifulSoup to say, "When you reach 'div class=result', put the number on a new row in column A and put the information associated with that in a list next to it in column B. I would post code, but I don't know how to do this at all and am looking for some direction. Thanks!

Comment: How are you pulling the divs from the page? With `find_all("div", {"class" : "result")` or something similar?

Comment: `div = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class":"result"})` Yeah, this is the code to pull it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it then would be:

```
# grab all the result elements
divs = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class":"result"})
# loop through the result elements
for div in divs:
    number = div.find('span', {'class': 'number'})
    # do the rest of your code here
```

Comment: Correct. So this will print all of the information inside the div that I want. I print that into column B. Now my problem is that I want to take the number that is also inside that div, and print it in column A next to all of the associated information.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When creating a csv, you don't create column A in it's entirety before moving to column B. It's built one row at a time. So if you have the number for column A place it there, put the data you want into column B, then move on to the next row, in this case the next iteration of the for loop.

Comment: csv? I'm writing it directly into an excel sheet using xlsxwriter. I'm not creating a csv file.

Comment: Can you show the code that you have now so I can see how it can be modified?

Answer (score -1):

It would be easy to say if you would show the exact result or the format of the result you would want. Otherwise what @wes mentioned would suffice.Thanks !